# Array Filter In swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I want to add on response on another array whose quantity greater than zero. Can it is possible without iterating my array. Is their any function because my array has lot of value. Please help any help would be appreciated.

```
{
            id = 1;
            img = "http://alatiffy.com/admin/uploads/1478601364.png";
            name = "Executive Lunch Tiffy";
            price = 99;
            quantity = 1;
        },
            {
            id = 2;
            img = "http://alatiffy.com/admin/uploads/1478601409.png";
            name = "Deluxe Lunch Tiffy";
            price = 149;
            quantity = 0;
        },
            {
            id = 4;
            img = "http://alatiffy.com/admin/uploads/1478583806.jpg";
            name = "KADHI PAKODA CHAWAL";
            price = 59;
            quantity = 1;
            status = Y;
        },
            {
            id = 2;
            img = "http://alatiffy.com/admin/uploads/1478583832.jpg";
            name = "DAL MAKHNI CHAWAL";
            price = 59;
            quantity = 0;
            status = Y;
        },
            {
            id = 5;
            img = "http://alatiffy.com/admin/uploads/1478583850.jpg";
            name = "SHAHI PANEER CHAWAL";
            price = 59;
            quantity = 0;

 status = Y;
    },
```

Comment: What do you want to filter in this array? have you make each dict in the array into separate object?

Comment: Use Swift `Array` and the `filter` function. Very easy.

Comment: @AanchalGupta Check my answer. You will get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

> **Swift 3.x**

Suppose you kept the above JSON data in an array of dictionary of type `[String:AnyObject]`

So your dictionary will be

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
```

And your array will be array of the above type of dictionary

```
var array = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
```

In order to filter the array for quantity greater than 0

```
let filteredArray = array.filter{$0["quantity"] as! Int > 0}
```

your `filteredArray` will contain all the dictionary objects which have quantity of greater than zero.

I would suggest you to make a model class of Food or Lunch item and apply filter on model itself rather than using dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

try this code,

```
   var filteredResults = arr.filter { $0.quantity > 0 }
```

Comment: Dictionary doesn't have a property called `quantity`.